# How to manage APK asset folder for the native android project in VS 2015?

Tags: android, android-ndk, visual-studio-2015

I've just started using the VS 2015 preview to mess around with native android applications. I noticed that the AndroidTest.Packaging project includes a res folder, but this project does not include an assets directory.

[image]

I tried creating an assets folder manually, but that didn't seem to work. (Either there is a bug in my asset reading code, or this approach is not correct.)

Does anyone know how to create an assets folder for the VS2015 android project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm stupid - make sure the asset folder is named 'assets' (exact case).